# Android studio google maps implantation error

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps

Hello I've been trying to get my android studio project to work but I keep running into error. This time the app is crashing on the emulator. I've added code for my main_activity.xml, mainactivity.java. the gradle and manifest.xml. I've tried many times watch over 20 tutorials on youtube and had no luck. I any knows what wrong with the code or where I can find a copy of a similar project all I need is for the map to work. I already have a api code .I just didn't post it.Any suggestion would be helpful.

. [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVNhf.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61FQx.png)

````
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.googlemaptutorail'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.googlemaptutorail"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    
}
```

```
mainactivity.java
package com.example.googlemaptutorail;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {

    }
}
```


```
main-activity.xlm (layout)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/maps"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" >
        </androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>

```




androidmanifest.xml
 ```
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Googlemaptutorail"
        to`ols:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="APIcode"> </meta-data>
        </activity>
    </application>

```
````

Comment: The first part of the code segment is the gradle.app

Comment: What tutorial are you following with this?